# How to obtain the average of the number of a field according to the term of taxonomy?

Tags: 8, views

I am using the default view Taxonomy term.

I added a "number" field to my article content type.

I would like to obtain the average of the fields of the nodes listed by term of taxonomy.

For example, I have two nodes, which have as fields numbers: 2 and 4, and whose term is common taxonomy: A.

I would like in the view of the term taxonomy A, get the average of the fields "number" of these nodes, namely 3.

I tried views aggregation, add two fields: a field of type "Content: title", with aggregation: Group together, and a field of type "AVG (Content: Note)", with aggregation: "Average".

But it does not work.

I tried to add different relationships, but without success.

Someone would know the right configuration of views to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a configuration that can do that out of the box on the Content type Views. But if it must be that exact Taxonomy Terms Views you can do it with the help of an additional module (check out [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) and [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator)).

But if you only want the result, to show the Average number on Term pages, then you can create a different View, of type Taxonomy term and display it as a Block on term pages. This type will work without additional modules.

1. Create `Term` Views type
2. Filter to your Vocabulary, filter Note field to be `Not empty`
3. Add the Taxonomy Name field, just to test, you'll see terms listed in separate Views rows
4. Add the Relationship to all content using the field `Content using Note`, (Relate each Content with a Note set to the term.) You can require this Relationship
5. DO NOT add any Sort criteria, sorting often messes up Aggregation
6. Add the Note Field, it will show separate Nodes' Note numbers in separate Views rows
7. Turn ON Aggregation
8. Edit the Note Field Aggregation and set it to `Average`, Group column `Value`

   You should now again only see individual terms in rows, and the Note will show the average number calculated
9. Check the Note field Formatter, the Default might round the numbers not to show decimal places, Unformatted might show more
10. If this is all working the last thing to do is to add a Contextual filter to filter according to the term page you're viewing: Add the Contextual for the field relating to your relevant Taxonomy terms and configure it:
     `When the filter value is NOT available`
    **Provide default value**
    **Taxonomy term ID from URL**
    **Load default filter from term page**
    `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
    **Specify validation criteria**
    **Taxonomy term ID**

    Now you can enter a term ID into Preview field and you'll see what the block will display on that term's taxonomy page.

Place the block in a region, configure the block, limit the Visibility to term pages etc.